System.InvalidOperationException: No sign-out authentication handler is registered for the scheme
I have simple api setup with Asp Identity , the login, create and 2fa routes are working fine, but when i try to call sign out I am getting the following error response
System.InvalidOperationException: No sign-out authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Identity.Application'. The registered sign-out schemes are: Identity.Bearer. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddCookie("Identity.Application",...)?
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.SignOutAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.SignOutAsync()
at Program.<>c.<<$>b__0_2>d.MoveNext()
my program.cs file, is there any configuration change I am missing here?
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql("Server=localhost;Database=PartnerPortal;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=Password@1;Ssl Mode=Prefer;"));

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<AgentPortalUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
                .AddApiEndpoints() ;

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
});

builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder();
builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.MapGroup("/account").MapIdentityApi<AgentPortalUser>();
app.MapGroup("/account").MapPost("/logout", async (SignInManager<AgentPortalUser> signInManager,
    [FromBody] object empty) =>
{
    if (empty != null)
    {
        await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        return Results.Ok();
    }
    return Results.Unauthorized();
})
.WithOpenApi()
.RequireAuthorization();

app.MapGet("/test", (ClaimsPrincipal user) => $"Hello {user.Identity.Name}").RequireAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();


public class AgentPortalUser : IdentityUser;


class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AgentPortalUser>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
}


In your code you used AddIdentityCore<AgentPortalUser>() which does not automatically register Identity.Application scheme, so you can add .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme) after AddAuthentication(), below is an example for you can be used as reference:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)
    .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)
    .AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);


